# Rails Association: Has Many...Through... With Multiple Sources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, model-associations

Let's say there are three models: `User`, `Event`, and `Invite`. Here's the table with some information about the model.

```
**User**
- First Name
- Last Name

**Event**
- Title
- Organizer_id (user who created it)

**Invite**
- Organizer_id
- Invitee_id
- Event_id
```

Now in the user model, an association is created between a `User` and `Invite`..

```
has_many :invites, foreign_key: "invitee_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :invite_infos, through: :invites, source: :event, dependent: :destroy
```

I want `invite_infos` to have **both** the information of the event as well as the information of the organizer by simplying calling `current_user.invite_infos`. Is that possible?

Comment: which models these two lines belong to? be more specific? has_many :invites, foreign_key: "invitee_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :invite_infos, through: :invites, source: :event, dependent: :destroy

Comment: I said "Now in the User model, an association is created..." that means they belong to the User Model.